# How do I create array of retrieved JSON values in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, json

I have a multiple JSON objects that I have to retrieve the value "title" for. I am successful in retrieving each of the "title" values, however, I am not sure how I can put all these title values into an `NSMutableArray` that I can later populate a `UITableView` with.

Currently, storyTitle (a `NSString`) returns several different strings, but they are all separate. For example, the console returns

```
2013-03-30 21:39:30.416 Appv0.1[32742:11303] (
    "Boys\U2019 lacrosse display drive at Watsonville Jamboree"
)

2013-03-30 21:39:31.799 Appv0.1[32742:11303] (
    "Volleyball teams currently undefeated midway through season"
)

2013-03-30 21:39:32.093 Appv0.1[32742:11303] (
    "Wrestling season ends with a CCS victory and 2 state berths"
)
```

How do I combine these strings into an array? Thanks in advance! Any help would be appreciated.

```
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

storyList =  [NSMutableArray alloc];

storyTitle = [res objectForKey:@"title"];

//create array of storyTitles
NSString * story1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", storyTitle];
//not sure how to do this array part 
storyList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:story1,nil];
```

**Edit:** If I do:

```
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            storyTitle = [res objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSString * story1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", storyTitle];
            [self.storyList addObject:story1];
        }
```

Console returns

```
array: (
"Boys\U2019 lacrosse display drive at Watsonville Jamboree",
"Boys\U2019 lacrosse display drive at Watsonville Jamboree",
"Boys\U2019 lacrosse display drive at Watsonville Jamboree",
"Boys\U2019 lacrosse display drive at Watsonville Jamboree",
"Boys\U2019 lacrosse display drive at Watsonville Jamboree",)
```

How do I make the array have all 3 separate stories?

Comment: There's a saying that insanity is doing the same thing over and over and expecting a different result.  When you do your loop you do not use `i` anywhere to vary what you select for `storyTitle` (nor is there anything else that changes per loop iteration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to add strings to an array?

As pointed out by sapi, `storyList` should be a property if you want to reuse it.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *storyList;
```

Then in your init method

```
self.storyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then somewhere in your code

```
storyTitle = [res objectForKey:@"title"];
[self.storyList addObject:storyTitle];
```

Comment: You'll probably want to create the `storyList` array as a property if you're expecting multiple results, though.  You can either call `reloadData` on your `UITableView` after each object is decoded, once at the end, when you know you've got them all.

Comment: I basically want to add strings to an array, but with the addObject:storyTitle, storyList returns just one storyTitle, not all of the storyTitles.

Comment: You can use a for loop to add all `storyTitle` with `addObject`.

Comment: @yeesterbunny Sorry, I am an Objective C newbie. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to iterate over the elements of the res dictionary (to get each one):

```
    NSMutableArray * storyList =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id item in res) {
        [storyList addObject:[item[@"title"]]];
    }
```

Note: 'item[@"title"]' is new ObjC syntax for '[item objectForKey:@"title"]'.